# Difference between wouldn't and didn't

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

What is the difference between *would not* and *did not*?

For example:

> I called my girlfriend but she **wouldn't stop**.
>   I called my girlfriend but she **didn't stop**.

Comment: Related http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/86445/

Answer (score 4):

I called my girlfriend but she wouldn't stop. It implies I had done my best to stop her, but she refused to stop doing what she had persisted. She had a will to disagree with me.

I called my girlfriend but she didn't stop. It implies she just continued doing something which I opposed her doing, but she didn't neccessarily have a negative attitude to my suggestion.

*Would* here is the past form of *will*, meaning *was/were not willing to do sth*. It lays more stress on the opposing attitude, not the action itself (doing what she had persisted).

Answer (score -5):

"I called my girlfriend but she wouldn't stop" - I can't think of any situation where I can fit this sentence. But if you add few words we can use that sentence with some alteration of meaning. "I called my girlfriend and I knew she wouldn't stop" - Self explanatory.

"I called my girlfriend but she didn't stop" - It narrates an incident, where it's pretty plain. You called her first, and then she ignored and walked on. I simple narration of past event.

Comment: **Intro**: "My girlfriend texted me that she is packing her things and leaving me." **Climax**: "I called my girlfriend but she wouldn't stop." **End**: "I am now alone." **Roll credits.**

Comment: _My girlfriend's mom told me that Amy had looked in herself in her room, threatening to commit suicide. I was alarmed, and told her I would try to talk her out of it. We hung up. Her mom called the police. I called my girlfriend but she wouldn't stop. She told me she had already taken 10 sleeping pills, and was going to keep taking them until the bottle was empty._ It's a sad narrative, but it shows that the first sentence can be used in some situations.