# Wouldn't say vs Didn't say

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense

1. The robber **wouldn't say** where he had spent all the money.
2. The robber **didn't say** where he had spent all the money.

What's the difference between two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

"*wouldn't say*" implies a refusal to say, whereas "*didn't say*" simply notes that it did not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Would not implies that he went against you and did not say out of choice, a refusal. Did not implies that either he was never asked so never told them, or he never told them.